# macOS NSView - How to give dynamic margin to left and right sides

Tags: swift, macos, autolayout, nsview

I have two views A(View Controller's view), B(is a NSView and subview of A). View B pinned to top, trailing, bottom and leading of view A. When I drag window view B grows according to auto layout constrains. Which is perfectly fine. At one point I want view B to stop growing and provide margin at leading, trailing between view A and B.

I did play around widthAnchor, so the margin is grows only at right(trailing) side and which is obvious. How can I give equal margin to left(leading) side as well.

> B.widthAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: 1000)

Code:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    let B = CustomNSView(frame: .zero)
    B.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    //detailView.autoresizingMask = [.width, .maxXMargin, .maxYMargin]
   // detailView.frame.size.width = 600
    view.addSubview(B)
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        B.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
        //B.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
        //B.widthAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: 1000),
        B.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
        B.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
    ])
}
```

Appreciate your inputs,
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to save the leading and trailing layout constraints and then change their constants when the view exceeds B's max width:

```
var bLeading: NSLayoutConstraint?
var bTrailing: NSLayoutConstraint?
var bMaxWidth: CGFloat = 1000

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let b = CustomNSView()
    view.addSubview(b)
    
    b.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    b.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    b.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    
    bLeading = b.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor)
    bTrailing = b.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)
    
    bLeading?.isActive = true
    bTrailing?.isActive = true
}

override func viewWillLayout() {
    let margin = view.bounds.width - bMaxWidth
    
    if margin > 0 {
        bLeading?.constant = margin
        bTrailing?.constant = -margin
    } else {
        bLeading?.constant = 0
        bTrailing?.constant = 0
    }
}
```